# Strange webserver exception after patching web farm

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

We recently patched our 12 servers, now have been getting the following exceptions across all servers when hitting URL similar to this... (URL has been modified)

http://thedomain.com/WebResource.axd?d=yj6P234W1h22bOvqe2sdf2f=

```
System.Web.HttpException - Invalid viewstate.
```

Stack trace:

```
at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptStringWithIV(String s, IVType ivType)
at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

UPDATE

```
at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, IVType ivType, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean signData)
    at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptStringWithIV(String s, IVType ivType)
    at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.DecryptParameter(NameValueCollection queryString)
    at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpResponse response, NameValueCollection queryString, VirtualFileReader fileReader)
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Any Event Log entries on the servers? Any client-side JavaScript errors?

Comment: Haven't been able to replicate the problem personally. The event log shows similar information as what is listed here ie: exception info. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you have different encryption keys for the servers, which results in one server not being able to decrypt ViewState generated on a different server. See the following for additional information on how to fix it:

- [How To: Configure MachineKey in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx)
- [Generate Machine Key Elements for Web Farms](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030514.asp)

Comment: Thanks Morten, I have checked and machinekey items all match in web.configs across the servers. One thing I did notice however was that separate applications hosted on the same webserver were using the same machinekey values - could this be a problem? From MSN: "If you want to isolate your application from other applications on the same server, place the <machineKey> in the Web.config file for each application on each server in the farm. Ensure that you use separate key values for each application, but duplicate each application's keys across all servers in the farm."

Comment: If the errors slowly disappear then it could be open browser windows with ViewState created before you patched the servers making the requests, since VS created with the old key would not be compatible with a new key. I doubt that it has anything to do with isolation across applications.